# Script Stopping After Loop (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a script that is (seemingly) randomly stopping at the end of a for loop.  It completes each iteration, and it completes everything within each iteration, but then it mysteriously stops.  As you can see, the "Moving on" alert never fires.  ANY help is appreciated!

**CODE:**

```
var sliderDirectionRaw = "top-left,left";
var sliderDirection = sliderDirectionRaw.split(",");
    for (i=0;i<=sliderDirection.length;i++) {
        if (sliderDirection[i].indexOf("-") >= 0) {
            sliderDirection[i] = sliderDirection[i].split("-");
                            alert("Multiple directions specified in iteration "+i);
        }
        alert("Direction iteration "+i+" finished");
        if (i == sliderDirection.length-1) {
            alert("Direction loop finished");
        }
    }
alert("Moving on from Direction loop");
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/k7cSE/1/

Comment: Tip: you can use the console to log your messages instead of alert, the command is: `console.log("my message")`. In firefox or Chrome you can press F12 to open the console. The error messages show up in the console as well.

Comment: And the error is: `TypeError: sliderDirection[i] is undefined` no mystery, just an error in your JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, wow!  Well, it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined" but that doesn't make sense!  It isn't undefined.  Additionally, I don't see how this could be the culprit because it still continues looping after that.

Comment: Wait...I get it.  I should have done less than instead of less than or equal to.  Not sure why it still continues with the loop, but...

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help. http://jsfiddle.net/k7cSE/2/

Comment: Logging stuff can help a lot, note that console.log will throw an error in IE unless you have the developer tools open (press F12). You can inspect values of your variable by logging them as wel: `console.log("value of myObject is:", myObject);` Works well in FF and Chrome as you can actually click on the logged object and inspect it's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a "<" in your for loop instead of a "<=" fixes your problem....